# How does Angular2 manage dependency injection?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I understand that to inject a dependancy into an Angular2 component, I simply annotate an argument in its constructor, like here with      `ThingService`. What I would like to understand is how Angular knows what to inject at runtime, as so far as I am aware, this is just TypeScript annotation and has no meaning at run time. What is the low level, internal mechanism of this to manage which providers are placed where in a component's constructor. If you were to roll this system yourself, how would it work. Is this a typescript mechanism I am not understanding?

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-thing',
  templateUrl: './thing.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./thing.component.scss']
})
export class ThingComponent {

  constructor(
    private thingService: ThingService) {
  }
}
```

Comment: have you referred this https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html?

Comment: That doesn't really clear it up for me. I know how I would use it, I know what it does, but I do not understand it clearly enough to implement it myself.

Answer (score 7):

What happens under the hood is that TypeScript preserves the metadata in the generated ES5 code. So the annotation in your constructor isn't actually gone, it's available at runtime and then Angular's DI can take it from there.

TypeScript always preserves that metadata if the following requirements are fulfilled:

1. Both compiler option properties - `emitDecoratorMetadata` and `experimentalDecorators` - need to be set to `true`
2. There has to be at least one decorator on the class (that's why some service classes use the `@Injectable()` decorator, otherwise the metadata for their dependencies won't be emitted)

I've written an in-depth article about that topic [here](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/09/17/resolve-service-dependencies-in-angular-2.html)

Answer (score 2):

If I understood correctly you are asking for a more theoretical(js behind the ts) answer.

According to what I've read; angular2 injection system creates an instance of that provider object/function and uses that instance in that component when you define it like that in the constructor. If you haven't provided it in the component that you are using then it will go to it's parent component, up to the module that it's been used. Each level has its own map of provider instances and the component will use the first instance that it finds when it traverses the injection tree upwards.

So the provider will be a singleton instance up to the point it is defined.

Comment: I'm looking for the mechanism with which Angular identifies which providers are to be placed in which order in a components constructor

Comment: @MildFuzz You mean like if you add another service to the constructor, which one will it call first? Like a cyclic dependency question?

Comment: If I had another service, and I inject it, how does Angular know that `ThingService` should be the first argument in the constructor, and not the second?

Comment: @MildFuzz It'd be the same order that you've defined in your constructor. I sense that you have a dependency cycle issue

Comment: yeah, but how? The type annotation has no meaning at runtime, as far as I am aware. How can I define a class, and dynamically know what dependencies it expects? That's what appears to be happening.

Comment: Good question, I wondered this myself. My guess is (therefore comment) that the Typescript compiler (with ExperimentalDecorators) treats constructor arguments (colon separated) not as Type declarations but as DI elements IF the class is annotated with the @ decorators. So if there is an @ Component decorator (or others), it treats those arguments as DI elements. This would also explain why you have to decorate your service classes with @ Inject in order to be able to use DI.